# Probability of variable using Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a variable **x** and its standard deviation **sigma**.  I know , mean **mu** .How can I compute probabilty of **x** (using normal distribution ) that it is less / greater than limit **a** or inbetween limits **a** and **b** by using Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probability that x is less than a:

```
normcdf(a,mu,sigma)
```

Probability that x is between a and b (b > a):

```
normcdf(b,mu,sigma) - normcdf(a,mu,sigma)
```

Comment: That's no fun!  Nice one, I've forgotten all of these functions.

Comment: THanx of all friends who answered my qustion

Answer (score 1):

Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma)

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/normpdf.html

Comment: I think that will give you the probability density for that particular point X.  It's been a while, though.

Comment: @ jonsca , I cann't follow you. How can I give mu and sigma as argument in error function. e.g., I mu=200, sigma=2*sqrt(3), a=199.994, I want to know probabilty of x less than a. answer is 0.0416 . How to do it with erf.....

Comment: See the comment by Jonsca. He already answered your question!

Comment: @shahbaba I looked up erf in Matlab again, I guess it doesn't allow you to input parameters.  See my upcoming comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By integrating the probability density function:
[image]

In practice, this is usually done by plugging values into the error function, which is `erf(x)` [in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/erf.html).  `erf(x)` is the integral of the above function.

Comment: @shahbaba Regarding your second question, the difference between the integrals will give you the probability `P(a<=X<=b) = erf(b) - erf(a)`

Comment: @shahbaba You need to generate some things by hand.  Make a vector of X values, find Y = normpdf(X,200,2*sqrt(3)) at each of those points.  Then integrate using `quad` between a and b for `P(a<=x<=b)` or from a to infinity for `P(x >=a)`

Comment: I think you could scale your boundaries into Z-scores (subtract the mean and divide by the std deviation) and then use the canned erf, but I think this way is probably more practical.

Comment: @shahbaba George has a very compact function that's handling all of this dirty work for us.